# Composite two CIImages and display in UIImageView issue

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, cifilter, ciimage

I'm having trouble combining two images together with `CIFilter`. What is going wrong here?

The below code creates a `UIImageView` and adds it to the view, then combines two images `imageA` and `imageB` with a `CIFilter`, and outputs the composite into the `UIImageView`.

However, the combined image is not displayed in the `UIImageView`, it remains blank.

---

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. What is the correct code to display the composite image into the `UIImageView`?
> 2. Is there more performant way in which to combine two images with `CIFilter`?

---

**Code:**

```
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
    imageView.contentMode = .Center
    view.addSubview(imageView)

    let imageA = CIImage(image: UIImage(named:"imageA")!)
    let imageB = CIImage(image: UIImage(named:"imageB")!)
    let imageFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAdditionCompositing")!

    imageFilter.setValue(imageA, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    imageFilter.setValue(imageB, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)

    if let imageCombined = imageFilter.outputImage {
        let image = UIImage(CIImage: imageCombined)
        imageView.image = image
    }
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Does this code even reach the line that sets the image view's `image` property?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, the code runs to the image property. No errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always had issues with straight `UIImage` << >> `CIImage` conversions. If you have a frame/size/extent you can work with, I recommend using a `CIContext` and creating a `CGImage` first:

```
let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
let cgImg = ciContext.createCGImage(imageCombined, from: imageCombined.extent)
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImg!)
```

Remember that creating a `CIContext` is "costly", so if you need to do this for multiple images, create one and use it for all rendering. Also, if you are using a `GLKView` someplace, use it's context.

Regards to question #2, your code looks fine. You could "combine lines of code but that does not affect performance. CoreImage doesn't "process" anything until you call for a filter's `outputImage`.

Comment: Thanks @dfd . I'll give this a go shortly. Any particular reason why straight UIImage << >> CIImage conversions could cause some issues? Is there an even better optimised way to combine images that are better for performance?

Comment: I honestly don't know why a straight conversion is flaky. I've always used the method above. That, combined with displaying things in a `GLKView`, is very good performance-wise. You can use this (along with sliders attached to input parameters) to achieve "real-time" filter rendering. Then, and only when needed, convert to a `UIImage`. One thing to remember - CoreImage (and GLKViews) are optimized to use the GPU. Testing in the simulator **will** give you poor performance. Before thinking you have a performance issue, try it on a real device.

Comment: Thanks very much @dfd for all that explanation.